$\mathbb E_X[1/\mathbb E_Y[1/f(X,Y)]]\leq 1/\mathbb E_Y[1/\mathbb E_X[f(X,Y)]]$
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to (E,\mathcal E)$ and $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to (F,\mathcal F)$ two random elements. Additionally let $f:E\times F\to (0,\infty)$ be measurable.  Then
$$\mathbb E_X\left[
\frac 1{\mathbb E_Y\left[\frac1{f(X,Y)}\right]}
\right]
\leq 
\frac1{
\mathbb E_Y
\left[
\frac 1{\mathbb E_X[f(X,Y)]}
\right]
}.$$
For $g:E\times F\to \mathbb R$, the notation $\mathbb E_Y[g(X,Y)]$ used above refers to the random variable
$$\omega\mapsto \int_F g(X(\omega),y)d\mathbb P_Y(y)
=
\int_\Omega g(X(\omega),Y(\beta))d\mathbb P(\beta).
$$

Note that when $f$ is purely a function of $X$, or a function of $Y$ (meaning that $f(X,Y) = g(X)$ or $f(X,Y)=h(Y)$), then both sides of the inequality are the same.
I tried to exploit Jensen's inequality: if $Z$ is a positive random variable, then $1\leq \mathbb E[Z] \mathbb E[1/Z]$.
I also tried to consider an i.i.d copy $(X',Y')$ and leveraging the equality
$$\frac1{
\mathbb E_Y
\left[
\frac 1{\mathbb E_X[f(X,Y)]}
\right]
} = 
\frac1{
\mathbb E_{Y'}
\left[
\frac 1{\mathbb E_{X'}[f(X',Y')]}
\right]
},$$
so that it remains to show that
$$\mathbb E_{X,Y'}\left[
\frac 1{\mathbb E_Y\left[\frac1{f(X,Y)}\right]}
\frac 1{\mathbb E_{X'}[f(X',Y')]}
\right]
\leq 
1,$$
which can perhaps be achieved by symmetry.

Probably it's better to start with $\frac{\mathbb{E}_Y(1/f')}{\mathbb{E}_Y(1/f)}$, where $f' = \mathbb{E}_X f(X,Y)$? Now it's possible to start with Jensen inequality.

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$
For simplicity, write $g:x\mapsto \E\left[\frac1{f(x,Y)}\right]$ and $h:y\mapsto \E[f(X,y)]$.
Note that the definitions of $g$ and $h$ involve only the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, and not the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. The inequality to be proved is
$$\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X)}\right] \E\left[ \frac{1}{h(Y)} \right]\leq 1,$$
which also involves exclusively the marginals.
We can therefore assume WLOG that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (i.e., we consider an independent coupling of $X$ and $Y$).
The inequality to be proved then rewrites as
$$\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X) h(Y)} \right]\leq 1.$$
The trick is to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as follows (while leveraging the positivity of $f$):
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X) h(Y)}\right]\right)^2 
&= \left(\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X)\sqrt{f(X,Y)}}\frac {\sqrt{f(X,Y)}}{ h(Y)}\right]\right)^2 
\\
&\leq \E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X)^2 f(X, Y)} \right]
\cdot 
\E\left[ \frac{f(X, Y)}{h(Y)^2}\right].
\end{aligned}
$$
By the law of the unconscious statistican, independence and Fubini's theorem,
$$\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X)^2 f(X, Y)} \right] 
= \int_E \frac 1{g(x)^2}\int_F\frac 1{f(x,y)}dP_Y(y) dP_X(x)
= \E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X)}\right]$$
and similarly
$$\E\left[ \frac{f(X, Y)}{h(Y)^2}\right] = \E\left[ \frac{1}{h(Y)}\right].$$
So by independence we conclude that
$$\left(\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X) h(Y)}\right]\right)^2 \leq \E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X) h(Y)}\right],$$
which rewrites as
$$\E\left[ \frac{1}{g(X) h(Y)}\right]\leq 1,$$
as wanted.
The inequality is tight only if the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is tight, i.e. when $f(X, Y) = C \frac{h(Y)}{g(X)}$ a.s. for some constant $C \geq 0$. We can also observe that this is also a sufficient condition: when there exists $g, h$ such that $f(X, Y) = C \frac{h(Y)}{g(X)}$, the inequality is tight.

You assumed implicitly that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I've submitted an edit to your answer that shows this can be assumed without loss of generality. Great answer otherwise, ingenuous use of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Thank you for this correction!
